# Why i'm getting "An open stream object is being garbage collected; call "stream.close()" explicitly"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, mysql-python

i have a weird error and can't find a fix for it. I'm searching since weeks for a solution, I found a few other stackoverflow articles about it, but sadly they doesn't helped me. Aside from this, I can't find many articles in google about my problem. I even tried to switch MySQL drivers to avoid this error, but it doesn't help. It's really frustrating, because it looks like there's no reason for this error.

I tried [aiomysql](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql), [asyncmy](https://github.com/long2ice/asyncmy) and even [peewee-async](https://github.com/05bit/peewee-async). I'm using Python 3.8 on Linux Debian 10.
And I found a [Pull Request](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql/pull/459) that "should" help to solve this error for aiomysql, but it was never finished/published/whatever.

So everytime I build a async mysql connection, execute a few queries and try to close the connection after it, I still get everytime the error `An open stream object is being garbage collected; call "stream.close()" explicitly`

So first of all, that's my function to start the async connection:

```
async def getConnection():
    mydb = await peewee_async.aiomysql.connect(
        host="123.123.123",
        user="admin",
        password="123",
        db="mydatabase")
    return mydb
```

And here is an example code, where the connection closing doesn't work.

```
@commands.Cog.listener("on_message")
async def on_message(self, message):

    mydb = await getConnection()
    mycursor = await mydb.cursor()
    if len(message.mentions) >= 1 and message.author not in message.mentions and not message.author.bot:
        await mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM afk WHERE memberid = %s", (int(message.mentions[0].id),))
        myresult = await mycursor.fetchone()
        if myresult and ".afk" not in message.content:
            status = myresult[1]
            time1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(myresult[2]))
            diff = datetime.now() - time1

            if (diff >= timedelta(minutes=2)) and (diff < timedelta(minutes=60)):
                zeit = strfdelta(diff, "{minutes} Minuten")

            elif (diff >= timedelta(minutes=60)) and (diff < timedelta(minutes=120)):
                zeit = strfdelta(diff, "{hours} Stunde und {minutes} Minuten")

            elif (diff >= timedelta(minutes=120)) and (diff < timedelta(minutes=1440)):
                zeit = strfdelta(diff, "{hours} Stunden und {minutes} Minuten")

            elif (diff >= timedelta(minutes=1440)) and (diff < timedelta(minutes=2880)):
                zeit = strfdelta(diff, "{days} Tag und {hours} Stunden")

            elif diff >= timedelta(minutes=2880):
                zeit = strfdelta(diff, "{days} Tage und {hours} Stunden")

            else:
                zeit = "Eben gerade"

            await mycursor.close()
            mydb.close()
            return

    await mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM afk WHERE memberid = %s", (int(message.author.id),))
    myresult1 = await mycursor.fetchone()
    # React on AFK User writes
    if myresult1 and ".afk" not in message.content:
        await mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM afk WHERE memberid = %s", (int(message.author.id),))
        if message.author.nick is None:
            updated = message.author.name.replace("AFK | ", "")
        else:
            updated = message.author.nick.replace("AFK | ", "")
        if not int(message.author.id) == int(message.guild.owner.id):
            await message.author.edit(nick=updated, reason="AFK-Status entfernt")

        await mydb.commit()
        await mycursor.close()
        mydb.close()
        return

    await mycursor.close()
    mydb.close()
```

Like you can see, I closed the connection at the end but still gets the error, everytime the event runs. I have that in other events too and really don't know why. Aside from that, I don't get the big error stacktrace, only this one-line error.

Comment: Try `await mydb.close()` ?

Comment: I tried that already too. I get then `TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. I needed to update Python3.8 to Python3.9.